# Iframes with Rails 5 not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

config/application.rb

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers.merge!({'X-Frame-Options' => 'ALLOWALL'})
```

I added this code but the iframes are still blocked.
I can't see it (even in private mode with Chrome and after restarting the server)

view/videos/show.rb

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="<%= @video.link %>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
```

The video isn't shown. 
Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Does any warnings show up in your browser dev tools? The web server might be adding conflicting headers which could make it revert back to ORIGIN.

Comment: Yes, I have this error

`Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJIrFfQ' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`

`5:97 GET https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJIrF4YjHfQ net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE`

Comment: If the video link something that you have control over the hosting or is this a third party video? It could be the video source doesn't allow remote iframing.

Comment: Try changing the video link to `https://www.youtube.com/embed/lJIrF4YjHfQ`

Comment: You're right, it's working with the new the video link !! Thank you a lot :)